# Transform the header and the column data separated by "|" into separate columns with certain header name and data rows in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have read a txt file in pyspark used for a homework with operator "|" separating 3 columns of data.
How can I separate these 3 columns in a proper array? This is what I have achieved so far:

```
+---------------------+
|bid|gender|department|
+---------------------+
|      1|M|Informatics|
|              2|M|Low|
+---------------------+
```

As you see the header is created but not separated as columns followed by the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by specifying **`delimiter`** option as **`|`** and read as **`.csv`** file in pyspark

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").csv("<path_to_csv_file>")
df.show()
#+---+------+-----------+
#|bid|gender| department|
#+---+------+-----------+
#|  1|     M|Informatics|
#|  2|     M|        Low|
#+---+------+-----------+
```

**`UPDATE:`**

```
#Save dataframe as file
df.write.mode("either overwrite/append ").option("header","true").save("location")

#writing to hive table
df.write.saveAsTable("<db>.<table_name>")
```

Comment: As you see I need both ways :-(

Comment: Anywhere to find how saving this df ?

Comment: Please check my `UPDATE` section of the answer!